# R - How to mutate strings into icons within one cell

Tags: r, ggplot2, icons, gt, mutate

I want to create a table with different symbols depending on a string. I have a big df with multiple character values in one cell. I created this simple example:

```
df = as.data.frame(c("AP1, BP3, CP2, AN2", "AN3", "BN1, CP3, AP3", "AP2, BN3, CN1"))
colnames(df) = "V1"

df$V2 = c("CP1", "BN2, CP1", "AP2, AN1", "CP3")
df$V3 = c("BP2", "AN2, CP2", "AP3, BN1", "CN1")

                  V1       V2       V3
1 AP1, BP3, CP2, AN2      CP1      BP2
2                AN3 BN2, CP1 AN2, CP2
3      BN1, CP3, AP3 AP2, AN1 AP3, BN1
4      AP2, BN3, CN1      CP3      CN1
```

I want to mutate the character values into different colored symbols with the letters A, B or C in it. For example "AP1", should be a light red square with an "A" in it. The first letter is the letter that should be in the symbol, the 2nd letter is either "P" or "N". P should be red, N should be blue. And the number in the string is the intensity of the color, so 1 is only light, 3 is strong.

I know gt-table and also how to mutate CP1 into a symbol like that. But the problem now is, that I have multiple entries within 1 cell.

I would like to devide each column into a P and N column and then list the individual strings in rows by 2, so that in the end I have something like that:

[image]

Any idea how I can easily transfer this df into a table like that?